# In setInterval , asynchronous function are getting in queue and making app freezes by memory leak, in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval, react-native-ble-plx

In setInterval , asynchronous function are getting in queue and making app freezes by memory leak, in javascript

//Below the function that's i am using.

```
setIntervalsForServices = async (
  forkDevice, forkParsedData,
  shockDevice, shockParsedData ) => {

    this.manager.stopDeviceScan();

    let startTimestamp = Date.now()
    let counter = -1;

    console.log("startTimestamppp", startTimestamp)

    let localForkEachFrequencyPerSecondArrayData = [];
    let localShockEachFrequencyPerSecondArrayData = [];

    let localForkTotalFrequencyValue = [];
    let localShockTotalFrequencyValue = [];

    if (this.state.recordingStart) {
        this.baseSecondInterval = setInterval(() => {
            let forkFrequencyIncremental = 0;
            let shockFrequencyIncremental = 0;
            let frequencyIncremental = 0;
            let baseFrequencyIntervalTime = this.state.frequency > 0 ? parseInt(1000 / this.state.frequency) : 1000

            var root = this
            counter++
            if (this.state.recordingStart) {
                this.baseFrequencyIntervalArray[counter] = setInterval((localCounter) => {
                    let currentTimestampX = Date.now() - startTimestamp;

                    forkFrequencyIncremental++;
                    shockFrequencyIncremental++;
                    frequencyIncremental++;

                    console.log("Data in inner setinterval ", this.baseFrequencyIntervalArray, localCounter)
```

// That's the asynchronous function gets called after a setinterval which getting queue and making app freezes in React-Native
// Read Characteristic

```
                    this.setCharacteristicsToFetchData(
                        forkDevice, forkParsedData, shockDevice, shockParsedData,
                        currentTimestampX, localCounter,
                        localForkEachFrequencyPerSecondArrayData, localShockEachFrequencyPerSecondArrayData,
                        localForkTotalFrequencyValue, localShockTotalFrequencyValue, this.baseFrequencyIntervalArray[counter]
                    )
                }, this.state.frequency > 0 ? parseInt(1000 / this.state.frequency) : 1000, counter)
            }

            this.setState({
                xData: this.state.xData + 1
            })
                        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

Comment: The first interval callback `this.baseSecondInterval = setInterval(() => { ` contains code to create another interval timer with a call back to increase the frequency of the next nested interval created on the next base timer callback. Without calling `clearInterval` on any existing timers, limiting the upper frequency of callbacks or changing `this.state.recordingStart`, the number of interval timers waiting to be serviced possibly gets large enough to freeze the app. Does CPU usage go up to 100%?

Comment: Thanks @traktor, No it's not 100%